# HTML5 video attributes like autoplay

Tags: html

I see the following code to embed HTML5 video

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My question is the query params given in the code above
autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0

Do that query params work directly with the video (meaning is that HTML5 standard which the browser understands) OR is this something which is mapped internally by the iframe page to the actual HTML5 attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

They are just parameters passed to `https://player.vimeo.com` which interprets them and creates the `<iframe>` content based on them.